# MediaWiki: workaround for watchlist restricted to 7 days?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm running MediaWiki 1.13.2.  When I go to my watchlist, I'm limited to only viewing the last 7 days (though MediaWiki should permit me to view the last 30 days).  I've tried:

1. Clicking the all button
2. Changing the URL
3. Changing the settings under MY PREFERENCES->WATCHLIST. When I save (e.g. 30 days) it resets back to 7 days!
4. Googling for an answer...

Anyone heard of this bug before?  Is there a workaround?  I can't see a setting anywhere for this to be a maximum.

**Update:** the solution below only affects **Recent Changes** - anyone know how to change the **watch list**? (Specifically, under MY PREFERENCES the Recent Changes now shows a maximum of 91 days but the watch list still shows a maximum of 7 days.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to 1.16 (current version at time of writing) the default was 7 days.  To change this you need to add this line to LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgRCMaxAge = 13 * 7 * 24 * 3600;
```

This will give a new maximum of 13 weeks.  (Change the "13" in the code above to specify a different number of weeks.)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't forget the ; at the end of the code ;-)

```
 $wgRCMaxAge = 13 * 7 * 24 * 3600;
```

And with my MW installation (1.15.4) this did not help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Martin. Shame about it not working with 1.15.4 - that's what I want to upgrade to! =:-(

Answer (score 0):

Not really a programming question. Not sure what could be going on, though you may have some luck updating to a newer version of Mediawiki. Version 1.13.2 is nearly 2 years old.

Changing the days parameter in the url should show the the changes those number of days.
http://www.yourwikidomain.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Watchlist&days=**10**

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. That's what I meant by 2 - I changed the URL (e.g. to =30) but the number of displayed days in watchlist remained on 7.